# Suitescript set 'Create PO' to dropship

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

[NetSuite] I would like to have a Suitescript to **Set the "Create PO" sublist Item field to 'DropShip' when a Sales Order is created via the user interface.** I would also like to add another **"if" to check a custom field.**

I have found a SuiteAwners article about setting that field:

"[Setting the Create PO field to null via SuiteScript](https://%5B1%5D:%20https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/35911/kw/set%20create%20PO)"  **Answer Id: 35911**
I have gotten the Suitescript 1.0 to work (I have got it to set the 'createpo' to 'DropShip', and **I have not been able to and another if statement to check a custom field** on the Sales Order)

**Here is the Suitescript 1.0 Code:**

```
function beforeSubmit(type)
{
  var count = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
  for (i=1; i<= count; i++)
  {
    var currentContext = nlapiGetContext();
    //setting of 'createpo' field only happens when the script is triggered via User Interface
    //add other if conditions here, if needed
    // 'createpo' values are Null, 'DropShip', or 'SpecOrd'
    if((currentContext.getExecutionContext() == 'userinterface'))
    {
      nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'createpo', i, 'DropShip');
    }
  }
}
```

I know that Suitescript 1.0 is deprecated so **I would love to rewrite it in Suitescript 2.0. Fortunately**, the SuiteAwnsers article has some code for that as well.

**Here is the Suitescript 2.0 code**

```
function beforeSubmit(type){
  var count = objRecord.selectLine({
    sublistId: 'item',
    line: i
  });
  
  for (i=1; i<= count; i++)    {
    var currentContext = runtime.executionContext();
    
    //setting of 'createpo' field only happens when the script is triggered via Web Services
    //add other if conditions here, if needed
    if((currentContext.getExecutionContext() == 'webservices'))        {
      objRecord.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'createpo',
        line: i,
        value: null
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Unfortunately, when I got to Create a new script in Netsuite it only gave me "Select 1.0 Script Type " as an option not "Select 2.0 Script Type".**

I know this is a bit of a long one so if you have made it this far round of applause! to sum it up there are two things I need help with

**1.** How can I **add an "if" that checks a filed value on the sales order** "before submit" on Suitescript 1.0

**2.** How Can I **get the suitescript 2.0 to work** (including the "if" that checks a filed value on the sales order "before submit")

**Just so you all know I am really new to scripting so if you have solutions please give as much detail as possible**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set the script version at the top of your script for it to be recognized as version 2:

```
 /**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
```

Next, for your script:

1. your count var is not getting a line count, it is selecting a line and you are passing an uninstantiated var i into it. You need to use record.getLineCount() instead:

   var count = objRecord.getLineCount({
   sublistId: 'item'
   });
2. Start your for loop at 0. In suitescript 2 all lists are 0 indexed.

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
3. Since you are referencing the runtime module, make sure it is included in your define statement.

The final script might look something like this:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/

define( ['N/runtime'], function(Runtime) {

function beforeSubmit(context){
  // get record from context
  var objRecord = context.newRecord;

  // get item list line count
  var count = objRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
  });

  // start for loop at 0. lines are 0 indexed
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)    {
    var currentContext = Runtime.executionContext();
  
    //setting of 'createpo' field only happens when the script is triggered via Web Services
    //add other if conditions here, if needed
    if((currentContext.getExecutionContext() == 'webservices'))        {
      objRecord.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'createpo',
        line: i,
        value: 'DropShip'
      });
    }
  }
}

return {
  beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
};
```

});

Hopefully this will get you started at least. The question is a bit confusing but this should get you a functional 2.0 script to start working with.